# bash not reading windows double backslash on Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, filepath, backslash, cp

I am having problems with running bash scripts on Jenkins. The bash script does not read server path as a path but as a string

In script:

```
cp -r "./app" '\\servername\Folder1\Subfolders'
```

In the log:

```
cp -r ./app '\\servername\Folder\Subfolders'
```

`'\\servername\Folder\Subfolders'` seems still evaluated as a string instead of a path in the Jenkins log. 
`\\servername\Folder\Subfolders` is the path I paste in windows file explorer, and can open and access the files.

All above were run ok on my local bash (Git Bash), but does not do the copy-paste job. It does not throw an error either.

Please help. I am totally confused. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to mix two worlds. The UNC notation does not work well from within bash. You need a proper file path, such as by mounting the UNC path at some point directly accessible by bash.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BobDalgleish

Searched about UNC. I was using `cp -r "./app" '\\servername\Folder1\Subfolders'`, and changed to `cp -r "./app" "//servername/Folder1/Subfolders"`

And in the log, it interprets both strings as path.